# dbms_utility.get_time : Track Execution time of transaction in PLSQL Procedure

Tags: sql, performance, plsql, query-optimization, oracle12c

I want to understand why task completed time ( time to execute procedure  107 sec) and sum of time taken by each transaction (3.81 sec) inside my plsql procedure is different in attached screenshot?

Please note: I have used dbms_utility.get_time package inside my procedure to track execution time of each transaction.
Here temp table means Global temporary table.

v_start := dbms_utility.get_time;

---insert statement----

v_end := dbms_utility.get_time;

v_diff := (v_end-v_start)/100;

dbms_output.put_line('Time Taken to insert meter events into temp table: '|| v_diff ||' secs');

[image]

Comment: First, could you show us how did you use `dbms_utility.get_time ` ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 added in the description.

Comment: "Tiаsk completed in:" also includes network round trip delays.

Comment: Does dbms_profiler report similar times?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I do not have access to views associated with dbms_profiler as of now. I will check and update you.

Comment: You have to create tables for dbms_profiler. I appreciate that may not be practical in a production environment.